# Why does the serial monitor output show some unidentified symbols?

Tags: serial

```
#define LED 13
#define BAUDRATE 9600
#define DEBUGOUTPUT 0
#define LED 13
#define powercontrol 10

// checksum variables
byte generatedChecksum = 0;
byte checksum = 0;
int payloadLength = 0;
byte payloadData[64] = {0};
byte poorQuality = 0;
byte attention = 0;
byte meditation = 0;

// system variables
long lastReceivedPacket = 0;
boolean bigPacket = false;

//////////////////////////
// Microprocessor Setup //
//////////////////////////
void setup() {
  pinMode(LED, OUTPUT);
  Serial.begin(BAUDRATE); // USB
}

////////////////////////////////
// Read data from Serial UART //
////////////////////////////////
byte ReadOneByte() {
  int ByteRead;
  while(!Serial.available());
  ByteRead = Serial.read();
  #if DEBUGOUTPUT 
  Serial.print((char)ByteRead);
  // echo the same byte out the USB serial (for debug purposes)
  #endif
  return ByteRead;
}

/////////////
//MAIN LOOP//
/////////////
void loop() {
  // Look for sync bytes
  if(ReadOneByte() == 170) {
    if(ReadOneByte() == 170) {
      payloadLength = ReadOneByte();
      if(payloadLength > 169)
      //Payload length can not be greater than 169
        return;
      generatedChecksum = 0;
      for(int i = 0; i < payloadLength; i++) {
        payloadData[i] = ReadOneByte();
        //Read payload into memory
        generatedChecksum += payloadData[i];
      }
      checksum = ReadOneByte();
      //Read checksum byte from stream
      generatedChecksum = 255 - generatedChecksum;
      //Take one's complement of generated checksum
      if(checksum == generatedChecksum) {
        poorQuality = 200;
        attention = 0;
        meditation = 0;
        for(int i = 0; i < payloadLength; i++) {
          // Parse the payload
          switch (payloadData[i]) {
            case 2:
              i++;
              poorQuality = payloadData[i];
              bigPacket = true;
              break;
            case 4:
              i++;
              attention = payloadData[i];
              break;
            case 5:
              i++;
              meditation = payloadData[i];
              break;
            case 0x80:
              i = i + 3;
              break;
            case 0x83:
              i = i + 25;
              break;
            default:
              break;
          } // switch
        } // for loop

        #if !DEBUGOUTPUT
        // *** Add your code here ***
        if(bigPacket) {
          if(poorQuality == 0) digitalWrite(LED, HIGH);
          else digitalWrite(LED, LOW);
          Serial.print("PoorQuality: ");
          Serial.print(poorQuality, DEC);
          Serial.print(" Attention: ");
          Serial.print(attention, DEC);
          Serial.print(" Time since last packet: ");
          Serial.print(millis() - lastReceivedPacket, DEC);
          lastReceivedPacket = millis();
          Serial.print("\n");
          switch(attention / 10) {
            digitalWrite(LED, HIGH);
            digitalWrite(LED, LOW);
          }
        }
        #endif
        bigPacket = false;
      } else {
        // Checksum Error
      } // end if else for checksum
    } // end if read 0xAA byte
  } // end if read 0xAA byte
}
```

Comment: A snapshot of the output would be quite helpful...

Answer (score 2):

It time to start stroking our crystal balls, what symbols?

Actually it doesn't really matter, `ReadOneByte()` is the cause, you are printing `ByteRead` without checking that it is printable.  Character greater than 127 will look strange when you print them out, only 32-126 are printable (127 is backspace) see http://www.asciitable.com/ for more details.  In this case I would print the value as a hex number, `Serial.println(ByteRead, HEX);`

If you are still getting symbols after changing that there may be other prints that have the same problem

Answer (score 0):

select the same serial **Baudrate** in the select which is in the bellow of the serial monitor window as you have put in the code.